# Rewriting Tearadata SQL to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, teradata

This is a bit abstract, but how could I rewrite the following TD SQL into a bigQuery SQL

```
SELECT UserID
      ,Created_DT
      ,MIN(CREATED_DT) OVER(PARTITION BY UserID 
ORDER BY CREATED_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS LEAD_CREATED_DT
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  This is a pretty straight-forward query.

Comment: BigQuery won't let you refer to alias LEAD_CREATED_DT at the same level where it is defined. You have to either use a subquery or repeat the whole expression (inside the CAST, in this case).

Comment: @Andrew my BQ knowledge is limited.